# For IF Loop not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, checkboxlist

I am trying to use a for-if loop to run through a few CheckBoxList controls, to see if a checkbox is checked. If checked, it will run an INSERT statement to the DB.

My first CheckBoxList (stapleCheckBoxList) works as it should (Eg. If i selected all 4 checkboxes, the corresponding items will be inserted into the db). However for my second CheckBoxList (seafoodCheckBoxList), it seems to only do an INSERT on the first checkbox that is selected. Could anyone identify whats wrong with my codes below?

```
protected void btnTSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        int intOrderNo = (int)Session["sOrderNo"];
        int Qty;
        int UnitPrice;
        string ProdId;

        if (txtPaxQty.Text != String.Empty)
        {
            UnitPrice = 12;
            Qty = int.Parse(txtPaxQty.Text);
            ProdId = "PK001";

            OleDbConnection DBconn2 = new OleDbConnection();
            DBconn2.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source="
                        + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ParissDB.mdb");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = DBconn2;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO itemsTable(iOrderNo, iProductId, iQty, iUnitPrice)"
            + "VALUES (@OrderNo, @ProductId, @Qty, @UnitPrice)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", intOrderNo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", ProdId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", Qty);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", UnitPrice);
            DBconn2.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DBconn2.Close();
        }

        for (i = 0; i < stapleCheckBoxList.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            String str = "";

            if (stapleCheckBoxList.Items[i].Selected)
            {

                str = stapleCheckBoxList.Items[i].Text;

                OleDbConnection DBconn = new OleDbConnection();
                DBconn.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source="
                            + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ParissDB.mdb");

                Qty = 0;
                UnitPrice = 0;

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = DBconn;
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO itemsTable(iOrderNo, iProductId, iQty, iUnitPrice)"
                + "VALUES (@OrderNo, @ProductId, @Qty, @UnitPrice)";

                //Staple

                if (stapleCheckBoxList.Items[i].Text == "Yang Chow Fried Rice")
                {
                    str = "ST001";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", intOrderNo);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", str);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", Qty);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", UnitPrice);
                    DBconn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DBconn.Close();
                }

                if (stapleCheckBoxList.Items[i].Text == "Pineapple Fried Rice")
                {
                    str = "ST002";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", intOrderNo);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", str);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", Qty);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", UnitPrice);
                    DBconn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DBconn.Close();
                }

                if (stapleCheckBoxList.Items[i].Text == "Mee Goreng")
                {
                    str = "ST003";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", intOrderNo);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", str);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", Qty);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", UnitPrice);
                    DBconn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DBconn.Close();
                }

                if (stapleCheckBoxList.Items[i].Text == "Fried Udon with Seafood")
                {
                    str = "ST004";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", intOrderNo);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", str);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", Qty);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", UnitPrice);
                    DBconn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DBconn.Close();
                }


                //Response.Redirect("Delivery.aspx");
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < seafoodCheckBoxList.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            String str2 = "";

            if (seafoodCheckBoxList.Items[i].Selected)
            {

                str2 = seafoodCheckBoxList.Items[i].Text;

                OleDbConnection DBconn = new OleDbConnection();
                DBconn.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source="
                            + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ParissDB.mdb");

                Qty = 0;
                UnitPrice = 0;

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = DBconn;
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO itemsTable(iOrderNo, iProductId, iQty, iUnitPrice)"
                + "VALUES (@OrderNo, @ProductId, @Qty, @UnitPrice)";

                //Seafood

                if (seafoodCheckBoxList.Items[i].Text == "Butter Prawns")
                {
                    str2 = "SE002";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", intOrderNo);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", str2);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", Qty);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", UnitPrice);
                    DBconn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DBconn.Close();
                }

                if (seafoodCheckBoxList.Items[i].Text == "Cereal Prawns")
                {
                    str2 = "SE001";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", intOrderNo);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", str2);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", Qty);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", UnitPrice);
                    DBconn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DBconn.Close();
                }

                if (seafoodCheckBoxList.Items[i].Text == "Thai Style Prawns")
                {
                    str2 = "SE003";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", intOrderNo);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", str2);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", Qty);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", UnitPrice);
                    DBconn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DBconn.Close();
                }

                if (seafoodCheckBoxList.Items[i].Text == "BBQ Squid")
                {
                    str2 = "SE004";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", intOrderNo);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", str2);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", Qty);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", UnitPrice);
                    DBconn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DBconn.Close();
                }

                Response.Redirect("Delivery.aspx");
            }

        }
```

Comment: It looks like there is alot of duplication in your code , just for changing the productId, could you use the value for the productId, then you dont need all those if tests against text.Maybe its not matching because the text is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
Response.Redirect("Delivery.aspx");
```

is inside your `for` loop. So the first time it goes through the loop, you are already redirected. Just move the redirect to after the `for` loop.

And you should SERIOUSLY think about refactoring your code. There's too much repeated stuff that you can convert into methods, among other things.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will convert it to a method.